# Unexpected token { ../node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/make-dir.js:85 } catch {

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, node-modules, aws-cdk, docsy

I am facing this issue while building my application-

```
2020-07-12 16:48:39 ....: 
                   ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)..


   
                        BUILD FAILED
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

I am unable to understand what is causing it. I am trying to migrate code from cfn to cdk. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: That shouldn't throw a SyntaxError. What version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: I am using v10.21.0

Comment: I was facing this for a project where it was using node v8.9.3 then changed it to 10.9.0 using nvm. It worked.

Answer (score 37):

Check this thread from GitHub: https://github.com/google/docsy/issues/265
Basically, what you need to do is to upgrade the node version to 10.0.0 or higher and update the fs-extra package to 9.0.0 or higher.
For me, it just worked with the update of node.

Comment: Yay after almost an hour of searching! For me, updating npm through the command line (while it ran successfully) wasn't enough, so I had to clean install from nodejs.org and it worked fine (took a LONG time to install though)

Answer (score 2):

As commented by Carlos, do this, please:

```
cd ~
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
sudo apt install nodejs
```

After this, check the version:

```
node -v
```

The result should be:

```
v14.16.0
```

Comment: Easy way to do it is to use `n` - https://github.com/tj/n